# Proguard enabling for only single java file- Android

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I want to apply proguard tool only for a single class file from project which also contains other libraries.
So how can i achieve this.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any solution for a single java file?

Answer (score 1):

ProGuard tries trim/obfuscate everything unless it's explicitly kept by a rule, so the trick you're looking for is create a rule that tells it to keep everything except for a particular class:

```
-keep class !com.yourpackage.example.class { *; }
```

This definitely provides what you asked for but I'm also wondering if that'd be useful in the first place. ProGuard doesn't just provide code obfuscation - it also removed unused code to make the APK smaller, so we should always try to apply it to as many things as we can.

Comment: I have tried this but it not obfuscating the entire project

Comment: Correct.. you can't obfuscate an entire Android project. Activities, Services, Views and so on (pretty much everything declared in AndroidManifest.xml) can't be obfuscated due to being accessed externally.